# How can I add value as a Additional parameter in WebMethodAdaptor or in a Http post?

Tags: angular, syncfusion

I tried to make a treeview, where the json come from a server using POST operation. In the post method, I need to send the value in the body. For this, I use WebMethodAdaptor and addParams to add value. Here is my code:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public hierarchicalData: Object[];
  public projectId = 'projectID';
  public value = 'C03374EC2';
  public field: Object;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
    new DataManager({
      url: SERVICE_URI,
      adaptor: new WebMethodAdaptor
    }).executeQuery(new Query().addParams(this.projectId, this.value))
      .then((e: ReturnOption) => this.hierarchicalData = <Object[]>e.result).catch((e) => true);
    this.field = { dataSource: this.hierarchicalData, id: 'pID', text: 'Name', child: 'Child' };
}
enter code here
```

Now the problem is the WebMethodAdaptor send data in the following formats,

{"value":{"params":{"projectID":"C03374EC2"},"projectID":"C03374EC2"}}

But I need,

{
    "projectID":"C03374EC2"
}

Here is the [example code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-view2) of a treeview using local data.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tree-view2

Actually, I need something like that. Is there any way to solve the problem using the syncfusion or any other way? Where a json come from the server using post method and shown like a treeview.

Answer (score 2):

You can check whether you have properly initializes the params in the serve side where you fetch the data.

**[Server side code]**

```
// initializes params at server side.
public bool requiresCounts { get; set; }
public int skip { get; set; }
public int take { get; set; }
public string data { get; set; }
public Dictionary<string, object> @params { get; set; }
```

While providing the above code snippet you will get the params in the following format.
[image]
This is how the additional parameters get added from the server side request.

For more information you can check the [addparams API](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/documentation/api/data/query/#addparams) and the [WebMethodAdaptor](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/angular/documentation/data/adaptors/?no-cache=1#webmethod-adaptor) documentation links. Share your code snippet (server side) or sample that replicates your issue if you still have the issue.